# Decompressing zip

Tags: c#, .net

I want to decompress zip file in console application in c#. When I Googled it the solutions I found was using

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile
```

But when I try to use it I get error "the namespace 'ZipFile' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO.Compression'"

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of .Net are you targeting?

Comment: .net 4.5 and a solution from the linked post helped. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using .NET 4.5 and your project has a reference to `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx